# Acceder a propiedades heredadas de una DLL

Tags: c#, herencia, dll

estoy realizando una aplicación la cual contiene una clase que hereda propiedades de otro proyecto, mi problema surge cuando compilo la primera aplicación de la que hablo e intento cargar las DLL compiladas de dichos proyectos en algún otro proyecto e intento acceder a las propiedades de la clase heredada, me indica que no es accesible, ¿Hay alguna forma de acceder a esas propiedades heredadas?

Por ejemplo, en un proyecto tengo la clase:

```
public class MiClasePrincipal
{
   public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

Y en otro proyecto tengo la clase:

```
public class OtraClase : MiClasePrincipal
{    
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando compilo los dos proyectos, me genera dos DLL distintas, pero cuando agrego la referencia a esas dos DLL en un proyecto independiente e intento acceder a la propiedad Id de la clase "OtraClase" me manda un error, ¿hay algo que estoy haciendo mal o de plano no se puede hacer lo que estoy intentando?

Comment: Estas utilizando capas? (Negocios, Entidad, Web o como las conozcas), si es esto y tienes en dos proyectos dentro de la misma solución, intenta agregar la referencia del proyecto correspondiente para que puedas acceder a las propiedades de la clase desde otra capa.

Comment: ¿Qué error te manda?

Comment: Prueba fijándote en carpeta bin del proyecto independiente, obvio después de compilar, si las dos dlls o al menos una (la de mi clase principal, o la de OtraClase) están, si alguna falta colócala y me avisas, creo que puedo dar una respuesta extensa de esto.

Comment: @Fernando sí estoy usando capas, pero el problema es cuando quiero intergrar las DLL generadas de las soluciones en otro proyecto, ya agregue las DLL de los dos poryectos pero aun asi no me permite acceder a las propiedades de la clase heredada